# How to execute Promise.all only after an array of API calls finishes and catch the error if one of them fails?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, redux-toolkit

I am trying to implement a redux action that iterates an array of items making an API call for each; what I want is to set the success state only after all the items of the array have been successfully sent. But if one of them fails I want it to go to the catch and set the failure state instead.

What is happening now is that the setOpenAccountSuccess inside the Promise.all is run even before all the items are sent and even if one of them fails.

What would I need to change to make it work? Thanks in advance. Here is the code I have:

```
export const openAccounts = (data, userId, addressId) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(AccountsReducer.setOpenAccountsLoading());

  try {

    const openAccountsPromise = data.selectedProducts.map(async product => {
      let formatedData = setOpenAccountAndProductData(data, userId, addressId, product);

      await AccountsService.openAccounts(formatedData);
    });

    Promise.all(openAccountsPromise).then(dispatch(AccountsReducer.setOpenAccountSuccess()));

  } catch(error) {
    dispatch(AccountsReducer.setOpenAccountFailure(error.response?.data));
  }

}
```

Comment: use `await Promise.all(openAccountsPromise)`. If any of the promises is rejected, this will raise an exception that will be caught by `catch`

Comment: `.then()` takes a callback *function* as its argument, but you are immediately calling `dispatch` and passing its return value as the argument. But why are you using `.then()` at all in an `async` function? Use `await`!

Comment: Indeed, shouldn't have been using then inside this function. @Emiel Zuurbier's answer helped solve the issue. Thanks for responding Barmar, Bergi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you return the `Promise` from `AccountsService.openAccounts` in the `map` loop to collect all of the promise values.

Then `await` the `Promise.all(openAccountsPromise)` call. Since both the loop and the `Promise.all` are in the same `try / catch` scope, any of the failed promises will be caught in the `catch` block.

```
export const openAccounts = (data, userId, addressId) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(AccountsReducer.setOpenAccountsLoading());

  try {
    const openAccountsPromise = data.selectedProducts.map(product => {
      let formatedData = setOpenAccountAndProductData(data, userId, addressId, product);
      return AccountsService.openAccounts(formatedData);
    });
    
    await Promise.all(openAccountsPromise);
    dispatch(AccountsReducer.setOpenAccountSuccess();

  } catch(error) {
    dispatch(AccountsReducer.setOpenAccountFailure(error.response?.data));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Appreciate it.